# Make an image stretch halfway into the website which is then followed by a gradient

Tags: html, css

Image added if I cannot describe it accurately or you want a more visual representation of what I'm trying to do.
I want to make an image stretch so that it covers almost halfway (can be more or less than half) down the page but it has a black overlay to make the text readable which is a linear gradient starting from the top as an overlay and ending with the image as black. Which then continues as a gradient (must not be the same continuous gradient, can be another element) from black to blue to green which matches my footer.

First, I tried to make an empty div for image and an empty div for the overlay, but it made me use too many position: absolute; So thought against using that.

```css
&__img {
  background-image: url(../images/eugene-chystiakov-YElySQuyUV4-unsplash.jpg);
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

&__overlay {
  background-color: rgba(black, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

then I used the background image on the body like this

```css
body {
  // to make background image stretch the whole page use it on body tag
  background-image: url(../images/eugene-chystiakov-YElySQuyUV4-unsplash.jpg), linear-gradient(rgba(black, 0), rgba(black, 1));
  // to make the gradient work use background attachment
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(black, 0.7);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-position: center;
}
```

but now the image does not scroll with the page. If I remove background-attachment: fixed the image does scroll but the gradient stops at the 100vh height and keep repeating when scrolled. What should I do? I have attached an example image of what I'm trying to do.

This is the HTML used on the first attempt. The next CSS code did not require HTML markup as it was used on the body.

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="container__img">
    <!-- <img src="./images/eugene-chystiakov-YElySQuyUV4-unsplash.jpg" alt="" /> -->
    <div class="container__overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <header class="container__header header">
    <div class="header__text">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="header__CTA">
      <a href="#" class="header__btn header__btn--primary">Lorem</a>
      <a href="#" class="header__btn header__btn--secondary">Ipsum</a
                    >
                </div>
            </header>
      
      ...
      ...
      ...
</section>
```

If there is anything missing please say so and I will add that.

Edit: I realised that I do not 2 gradients one for overlay and one from transparent to black. I can just use one starting as an overlay and ending as black. But that did not solve the problem.

Edit 2: Added the HTML markup.

Edit 3: Tried removing background-attachment property.

[here is what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk7ZG.jpg)
The image is a placeholder from Unsplash.

Comment: Kindly add HTML markup as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to have an overlay completely covering your section with a bg image you can define a pseudo-element :after or :before and give it a position: absolute and make sure to give position: relative to the parent section so pseudo-element will be staying inside the flow of the document.

```css
.bg-black {
            background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616765118757-f5c165c30d93?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1482&q=80);
            position: relative;
            height: 90vh;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
        }

        .bg-black:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: #00000070;
        }

        .footer {
            padding: 15%;
            background: rgb(11, 11, 11);
            background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(11, 11, 11, 1) 0%, rgba(20, 55, 79, 1) 41%, rgba(48, 170, 255, 1) 100%);
        }
```

```html
 <div class="bg-black">
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
```